# CAAnimation layer cancels previos transformation of the view

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation, caanimation

I am using a simple transformation animation to an UIIMageView.

```
    [UIView animateWithDuration:2 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState|UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        CGAffineTransform translate = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0, -[self percentFromHeight:20]);
        clueImage.transform = translate;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [self.cluWordSelectionView setaWordsObjects:[NSArray arrayWithArray:[self.whiteCard clueWordObjectsForSoundAtIndex:self.index]]];

        [self addSubview:cluWordSelectionView];
        [clueImage.layer addAnimation:[Animations shakeAnimation] forKey:@"shake"];

    }];
```

As you can see after the completion I am adding an other shake animation to the view:

```
[clueImage.layer addAnimation:[Animations shakeAnimation] forKey:@"shake"];
```

Which looks like that:

```
+(CAAnimation*)shakeAnimation {

CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];

CGFloat wobbleAngle = 0.06f;

NSValue* valLeft = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(wobbleAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)];
NSValue* valRight = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeRotation(-wobbleAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f)];
animation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:valLeft, valRight, nil];
animation.beginTime = 3;
animation.autoreverses = YES;  
animation.duration = 0.125;
animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;  

return animation;

}
```

The problem is that when the  `shakeAnimation` starts the view "jumps" back to it's original position. How can I prevent that and Why this is happening?

Thanks

shani

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new animation should take the current transform (translation) into account:

```
    CATransform3D leftTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(wobbleAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    leftTransform = CATransform3DConcat(layer.transform, leftTransform);
    CATransform3D rightTransform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-wobbleAngle, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    rightTransform = CATransform3DConcat(layer.transform, rightTransform);

    NSValue* valLeft = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:leftTransform];
    NSValue* valRight = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:rightTransform];
```

Where `layer` is the layer that will be animated.

Comment: Thank you very much, BTW After I am done I am calling  [self setTransform:CGAffineTransformIdentity]; to the view and remove all animations on the layer. The next time That I am trying the animation the view animation does not work. ant Idea why?

Comment: I think it is better to post some code to explain this problem. Also, if you think this is independent from the current question, it is probably better to post a new one.